# python Linked List move backwards and move forward

Tags: python, linked-list

How can reorder the list so that it starts with the first occurrence of the smallest element and repeatively moves backwards by one step and forward by three steps?
I can only find the smallest element (for example ,I got 5 in the following test)? So how can I get the list (5, 53, 65, 33, 51, 62, 61, 38, 74, 45, 97, 49)?

```
class ExtendedLinkedList(LinkedList):

    def __init__(self, L = None):
        super().__init__(L)

    def rearrange(self):
        node = self.head
        if not node:
            return None
        Min = node.value
        while node:
            if node.value < Min:
                Min = node.value
            node = node.next_node
        return Min


---------test---------

LLL = ExtendedLinkedList([49, 97, 53, 5, 33, 65, 62, 51, 38, 61, 45, 74])

LLL.print()

print(LLL.rearrange())
```

Comment: Well, first, you're going to have to keep track of the min _node_, not just the min _value_, if you want to be able to move backward one step from that node.

Comment: Second, you're probably going to need to use a doubly-linked list, and that looks singly-linked. While, oddly enough, the specific requirements mean there's a way to do this pretty efficiently with a singly-linked list, it's probably not what you want, and requires some cleverness.

Comment: @abarnert I am not quite sure what's  the difference with min node and min value, maybe I need value and put value in a list?

Comment: So I have to wonder: are you in the same class as [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021557/python-linked-list-minimum-value/30021609#30021609), and also asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: @cge I m not quite sure, maybe have the same question, just confused moving backwards and moving forward, cause tried several times.

Comment: Are you using a singly or doubly linked list (do you have a previous_node as well as a next_node)?

Comment: @cge yes, i am using a single linked list.

Answer (score 1):

So you're doing better than what I assume is [your fellow student](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021557/python-linked-list-minimum-value/30021609#30021609). You have the minimum part worked out. But now here's the question: are you using a doubly-linked list (the sane way to do this) or a singly-linked list (the fun way)? And do you want to give a sane answer, or a fun answer?

The difficulty abarnert is mentioning is that in order to *find* the minimum value, you have to go through the entire list and keep track of the *value*, but in order to then *start* from there in gathering values, you'll need to keep track of the node itself, because otherwise, when you get to the end of the list, you'll know what the minimum value was, but you'll have no way of getting back there! There are a few options here. One is that you can store both the min value and min node when going through. The other is that you can store just the node, and compare values of nodes.

Now, having done that, you'll have the minimum node to start from.

**The sane choice**: you have a doubly linked list. Each node has a `next_node` that points to the next node, and a `previous_node` that points to the previous one. Going back and forward is easy, and I don't think it needs much explanation.

**The fun choice**: you have a singly linked list. You must always move forward! But that's alright, if you make some slight changes. When finding the minimum, instead of finding the minimum node, find the node before it; let's call it A. Now start making your rearranged list. Do it by first putting on the value of the node after A, then putting the value of A. Now move forward *two*. Add the value of the node *after* that, then add that node. And so on... In this way you never actually have to move backward.

---

In writing this I did not notice the 97,49 at the end of your example. Do you need to loop around too? That can also be done in both cases. You can just set the last node's next_node to the first node after the minimum finding part, and then when reordering, check to make sure you haven't gotten all the way back around.

---

So playing around with this, I managed to get the following rather compact code to work (I use `nn` instead of `next_node` and `v` instead of `value`):

```
def reorder(f):
    n,a=f,f
    while n.nn:
        a,n=[a,n][n.nn.v<a.nn.v],n.nn
    n.nn,ff=f,a.nn
    while a:
        a.nn.nn,a.nn,a=[(a,None,None),(a,a.nn.nn.nn,a.nn.nn)][
            (a.nn==ff)or((a.nn.nn!=ff.nn)and(a.nn.nn.nn!=ff.nn))]
    return ff
```

Comment: yes, I need. Cause I wanna keep all the elements in this list.

Comment: Replacing the good names with one- and two-letter names like this obfuscates the code and makes it much harder for a novice to figure out what you're doing. She has enough challenges figuring out the abstractions; no reason to hide those challenges under irrelevant ones…

Comment: The explanation was intended to teach the abstractions and methods in a  way that would be helpful. Putting specific, usable code in response would have just been doing her homework for her even if she didn't copy it directly. I put the code to show it could be done using the method I described, and as a compactness exercise for myself, while not making it directly helpful; the names are *not* the most obfuscated part. If anything clear names would make the absurdity clearer. I was tired at the time, though, and perhaps not thinking; I would be fine deleting the code if it would be better.